# InsertBefore method: Object doesnot support this method or property error in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a XML structure and am trying to add child nodes to child node of the root element. I am using insert before method but am getting object doesnt support this property or method error. Below is the code I have:

```
Sub GenerateXMLBodyForNewTestCreation()
    Dim requestTemplate, cookie, createPerfTestURL As String
    Dim noOfScripts, i, sample As Integer

    requestTemplate = Sheets("XMLSampleForCreatePerfTest").Range("B1").Value
    Set CreateTestXMLTemplate = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    CreateTestXMLTemplate.LoadXML (requestTemplate)
    noOfScripts = Sheets("ScriptDetails").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set root = CreateTestXMLTemplate.DocumentElement
    Set root1 = CreateTestXMLTemplate.SelectNodes("//Test/Content/Groups/Group")(0)

    For i = 2 To noOfScripts
        Set y = root1.CloneNode(True)
        sample = root.InsertBefore(y, root1(0))
    Next i

    CreateTestXMLTemplate.Save ("C:\Users\rrayudu\Desktop\XMLBody.xml")
End Sub
```

It may be a silly mistake but am struggling to get it working.

Comment: Please note that `Dim noOfScripts, i, sample As Integer` only declares `sample` as `Integer` but all the other as `Variant` if no type is specified. You need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim noOfScripts As Integer, i As Integer, sample As Integer` • Also please clarify in which line the error occurs. • And I suggest to use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Error is coming at sample = root.InsertBefore(y, root1(0)) line